# How to hide Kubuntu apps from the Ubuntu desktop environment and the opposite?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, default-programs

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and when I heard about KDE plasma 5.13 I decided to try it, and be able to use both DEs. However, I found my Ubuntu dock cluttered with KDE apps like Dolphin and Okular... I want each desktop environment to have its default built-in apps but I don't want it to have the other's. How do I go about that? I don't want to hide the apps manually, I would rather have a script take care of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit: I  tried making a bash file to make KDE apps only visible in KDE after following instructions from a UNIX stackexchange post. Here is its content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/share/applications/kde4/ || exit
sudo for i in *.desktop; do echo "OnlyShowIn=KDE" >> "$i"; done
```

and ran it with the following command: `$ sudo bash default_apps_restricter.sh`
However, I got this output:

```
default_apps_restricter.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
default_apps_restricter.sh: line 3: `sudo for i in *.desktop; do echo "OnlyShowIn=KDE" >> "$i"; done'
```

Please help!

Comment: do I add a line saying OnlyShowIn=Gnome for gnome apps? or is it OnlyShowIn=Ubuntu and where are the default apps' .desktop files located for each of the DEs?

Comment: Also for KDE apps do I type OnlyShowIn=KDE or Plasma or Kubuntu?

Comment: `OnlyShowIn=KDE` should work but you may have to run `sudo update-desktop-database` after making the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `.desktop` launcher associated to each application and add `OnlyShowIn` or `NotShowIn` keys accordingly. The `.desktop` files can be found in `/usr/share/applications/` (and some in `~/.local/share/applications/`).

But it's not recommended to edit the files in `/usr/share/applications/` (they'll most likely be overwritten once an associated package gets updated). Instead copy the `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the copied file.

To make an application visible only in GNOME add the following line

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

and to make an application invisible in GNOME add the following line

```
NotShowIn=GNOME;
```

Comment: I tried to automate that but it doesn't work. Could you please take a look at my edited post?

Comment: @Oussema Have you checked whether `OnlyShowIn=KDE;` got appended to the files (`;` is needed)?

Comment: Ok, I sorted it out by removing sudo from the bash file but it turns out only three apps are in /kde4 and I have to go through the rest manually. Thank you for your help I will just go one by one.